# Unable to generate token with refresh_token

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0

I am passing a refresh token to my local host server but getting unsupported grant type response(Please see the image).
[image: Refresh Token Postman Request]

I am using the following code to generate token using refresh token.

```
public class MyAuthorizationServerProvider: OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated(); //
    }
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);

        if (context.UserName == “admin” && context.Password == “admin”)
        {
           identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, “admin”));
           identity.AddClaim(new Claim(“username”, “admin”));
           identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, “admin”));
           context.Validated(identity);
        }
        else if (context.UserName == “dmuser” && context.Password == “dmuser”)
        {
           identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, “dmuser”));
           identity.AddClaim(new Claim(“username”, “dmuser”));
           identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, “dmuser”));
           context.Validated(identity);
        }
        else
        {
           context.SetError(“invalid_grant”, “Provided username and password is incorrect”);
           return;
        }
    }

    public override async Task GrantRefreshToken( OAuthGrantRefreshTokenContext context)
    {
     // chance to change authentication ticket for refresh token requests
        var newId = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Ticket.Identity);
        var newTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(newId, context.Ticket.Properties);
        context.Validated(newTicket);
     }
 }
```

If anyone has any idea why my GrantRefreshToken() method is not invoking while generating a new token using refresh_token .
Please reply!
Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score -1):

Try with headers as shown below. Refer [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6)

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
     Host: server.example.com
     Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
     Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

     grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but still it's not working.
The GrantRefreshToken() method is not invoking.
Can you pleae tell how to debug?

Comment: Is it working on your postman request? If so we can dig into the code. You can also try Curl to test your requests.

Comment: It's not working on postman request.(Please check the attached image)
When I am giving postman request , the method ValidateClientAuthentication is getting invoked but the next method i.e. GrantRefreshToken is not getting invoked.

Comment: A bit late on a possible answer but could this post help solve the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209394/why-grantrefreshtoken-method-is-not-called-oauth2-asp-net-web-api